# Is there anything Amazons can do about dwarves?

Tags: blood-bowl-legendary-edition

I was thinking of playing amazons. I've heard they're infamously bad against dwarves. Most of their units have tackle, and they're also the tankiest in the game. Amazons are supposedly helpless against them. In such a match-up, what should an Amazon player do? Can they play like an agility team against them despite the lack of dodge (they do move faster than dwarves, just like everything else). Should the Amazon player just concede to mitigate having their players die? Is it completely futile? Is there really any good response to this match-up?